# Changing SQL Server2000 settings after converting to VM?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2000, vmware, ssis-2008

We have migrated a SQL 2000 server to VM and I am wondering what changes will need to be made on the VM?

After the VM migration an SSIS package that transferred data from the 2000Server to a 2008Server will not connect. Nothing changed on the 2008Server but none the less the SSIS connection fails to authenticate. I can log in remotely from the 2008Server to the 2000Server using the credentials in the SSIS package.

So, is there anything that needs to be configured on the VM side that should be configured? I have checked services, account privileges, etc. The two servers can communicate, ports are open, osql -L and sqlcmd -L see the servers. Nothing on the VM server has changed from the physical server configuration wise.

Comment: What error are you getting with the authentication failure?

Comment: OLE DB error 0x80040ed Login failed with username. Though I have verified that the credentials are correct.